# How can I get the Android Version with a Property Provider in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, gwt

I want to detect if the users browser is from IOS, Android or whatever and also I want to detect the android version.

I think I can do this with a property provider in my gwt.xml file like this:

```
<define-property name="mobile.user.agent" values="android, iphone, not_mobile" />
<property-provider name="mobile.user.agent"><![CDATA[
  {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.indexOf('android') != -1) { return 'android'; }
    if (ua.indexOf('iphone') != -1) { return 'iphone'; }
    return 'not_mobile';
  }
]]></property-provider>

<!-- Constrain the value for non-webkit browsers -->
<set-property name="mobile.user.agent" value="not_mobile" >
  <none> <!-- Actually means NOR, in this case "not safari" -->
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="safari" />
  </none>
</set-property>
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ConditionalProperties

**Is there a way to detect the Android version of the users device?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSNI:

```
public static final native double getAndroidVersion() /*-{
    var ua = $wnd.navigator.userAgent; 
    var match = ua.match(/Android (\d+(?:\.\d+)+);/);
    return match = match ? match[1] : 0;
}-*/;
```